# Proper type for function resolving Promise values of a an Object: {[key: string}: Promise<T> => {[key: string]: T}

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

I'm having a function that will iterate over the fields of an object, await/resolve their values and return a new object with the same fields but those fulfilled values.

I'm having trouble type this.

Any clue?

I've iterated around things like:

```
export async function promiseAllObject<
  T,
  Obj = { [k: string]: PromiseLike<T> },
  NewObj = {
    [k in keyof Obj]: T;
  }
>(o: Obj): Promise<NewObj> {
  try {
    const resolvedEntries = await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(o).map(async ([k, v]) => {
        const newVal = await v;
        return [k, newVal];
      }),
    );
    return Object.fromEntries(resolvedEntries);
  } catch (e) {
    // If one of the promised fields fails, fail the whole object
    return e;
  }
}

// Example:
 const o = { foo: 12, bar: 42, toto: 'hello' };
const op = lodash.mapValues(async v => v);
/*
  just to get Promise as objects' values
{
    foo: Promise<string | number>;
    bar: Promise<string | number>;
    toto: Promise<string | number>;
}
*/

const oResolved = promiseAllObject(op);
/*
Promise<{
    foo: unknown;
    bar: unknown;
    toto: unknown;
}>
*/
```

But either TS thinks the values are still Promises, or they are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `promiseAllObject` as follows (`ResolvedPromise` uses type inference operator [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)):

```
// infer resolved type of Promise, e.g. Promise<string> ~> string
type ResolvedPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer I> ? I : T

export async function promiseAllObject<O extends { [k: string]: PromiseLike<any> }>
    (o: O): Promise<{ [K in keyof O]: ResolvedPromise<O[K]> }> {
    // paste your implementation here
}
```

```
const oResolved = promiseAllObject({
    foo: Promise.resolve("foo"),
    bar: Promise.resolve(42),
    toto: Promise.resolve(true),
});
/*
oResolved: Promise<{
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
    toto: boolean;
}>
*/
```

[Sample Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOB7ANgNwgEwAoCdEFsBLeCAHgBUA%20KAXinKggA9gIA7DeKXA4swtgDMIOKAElqAfnFQAXPQBQC5mEQ5gUAIbwQbAMZRBAV33BCiNlDB4iJAILJkAeQBGAKwh7gpJ4xbtOKABvKABtAGt5eGAcAQBzAF15HlsIABlCcLJNNhBqAF9KBSgSqAAKRHknAEpkmz5SENCAaSgBKCyQREEoJyTYBBR0bHqSHxaEguog4tKAejmrbVYoLqNRQnwwZAh8dmBNMwsoAAsRCAV8pT0LaKhEOCQ0TForUYgHZ3dPYDKZ0sMiEq3HeADocINnmUAESCIHQ6oAGlmJRcmhwdV4JHBkPQZQALAAmJEoqDARDkzGpHFPPExIwQEn5aoAbgUcwAVAoHrjMFSGv9SnDgdFYmw4myAWiMVA2EZ8C4RJLSuTKVAXECdjk2YUFBy5kA)